# Consolidating multiple Wordpress loops

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have 3 loops each returning a taxonomy with different types , (client wants the ability to change text in a jQuery slideshow without coding). Can I integrate all 3 into 1 loop that queries the database for 3 separate types, returning posts in an unordered list like below, or am I stuck with using a loop for each type?

```
<ul class="sub-header-excerpts">
  <li> 
     <?php 
     $args = array( 'excerpts_textboxes' => 'Excerpt One', 'posts_per_page' => 1);  
     $loop = new WP_Query( $args );  
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  
     ?>      
      <span class="textbox-title"><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
      <span class="textbox-excerpt"><a href="#"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a></span>
     <?php endwhile; ?> 
  </li> 
  <li> 
     <?php 
     $args = array( 'excerpts_textboxes' => 'Excerpt Two', 'posts_per_page' => 1);  
     $loop = new WP_Query( $args );  
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  
     ?>      
      <span class="textbox-title"><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
      <span class="textbox-excerpt"><a href="#"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a></span>
     <?php endwhile; ?> 
  </li>  
  <li> 
    <?php 
     $args = array( 'excerpts_textboxes' => 'Excerpt Three', 'posts_per_page' => 1);  
     $loop = new WP_Query( $args );  
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  
     ?>      
      <span class="textbox-title"><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
      <span class="textbox-excerpt"><a href="#"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a></span>
     <?php endwhile;   ?> 
  </li>  
</ul>
```

---

### **Edit:**

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'excerpts_textboxes',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'Excerpt one', 'Excerpt Two', 'Excerpt Three' )
      ),
   )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters 
It does mention selecting multiple taxamonies:

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'quotes' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-quote' )
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I never tried querying multiple taxamonies at once, but I do rember it's a bitch